# Insert date to MySQL from generated row

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I want to ask you what I do wrong with insert date to table. I wanto to insert only date choosen by user, but it save me only 0000-00-00 00:00:00. Where I have a mistake?

**MySQL Table**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `transakcia` (
  `id` int(6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `description` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
)
```

**function Add** - add new row to table

```
function Add(){

    $("#example2 tbody").last().append(
        "<tr>"+
        "<td></td>"+
        "<td><input id='description' type='text' class='form-control'/></td>"+
    "<td style='max-width: 250px;'><div class='input-group'><div class='input-group-addon'><i class='fa fa-calendar'></i></div><input id='date' type='date' class='form-control' /></div></td>"+

    "<td><img src='./img/save-icon.png' class='btnSave'/><img src='img/delete-icon.png' class='btnDelete'/></td>"+
        "</tr>"
    );

        $(".btnSave").bind("click", Save);      
        $(".btnDelete").bind("click", Delete);
};
```

**function Save** - save new row to DB

```
function Save(){ 
var par = $(this).parent().parent(); 

var tddescription = par.children("td:nth-child(2)"); 
var tddate = par.children("td:nth-child(3)"); 

var description = tddescription.children("input[type=text]").val();
var date = tddate.children("input[type=date]").val();

jQuery.post("table_save_ajax.php", {
   description:description,
   date:date
},  function(data, textStatus){
   if(data == 0){
      $('#response').html("Successfull!!");
      $('td:nth-child(4)').hide();

      tddescription.html(tddescription.children("input[type=text]").val());
      tddate.html(tddate.children("input[type=date]").val());

   }else{
      $('#response').html(data);
   }
});
};
```

**table_save_ajax.php** - php to save date into table

```
<?php
include("config.php");
$description = $_POST['description'];
$date = $_POST['date'];
$errors = array();

$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO transakcia (description, date) VALUES ('$description','$date')");

if(!$sql){
   $errors[] = "ERROR INSERT";
}

if(count($errors) == 0){
echo "0";
}else{
    foreach($errors as $e){
        echo $e . "<br />";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: You need to make sure the php date you feed it, is in a format that mysql understands. And you have an sql injection problem.

Comment: yes, I should use `mysql_escape_string`. But know I want to solve functionality of the script. Try to write me exactly where is the problem. I wrote my table and way how i process data. So what I do bad. Where is mistake?

Comment: That depends on what `$_POST['date']` contains. You need to format that so that mysql understands it.

Comment: aaah... ok... now it is dd-mm-yyyy and mysql need yyyy-mm-dd maybe

Comment: i will try to re-order it

Comment: try `$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime( $_POST['date'] ) );`

Comment: good idea, but it doesnt work... I have to debug it... what is in this variable after send to php...

Comment: `$_POST['date']` is empty.. so problem will be in jquery... but where?

Comment: What is `$(this)` referring to in line#1 of `Save()`? Have you logged and checked what is the value of `date = tddate.children("input[type=date]").val()`?

Comment: I used this: `var date=$("#date").val();` and now it is good. Thank you for your usefull comments

Comment: @Salman - sorry I make source shorter because I want to show only the problem and do it as easy as possible. And this line I forgot to delete.